# Kinect for windows(first version) with ROS

Tags: ros, openni-kinect, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am try to use kinect for windows(first version) with ROS on a jetson

I tried both freenect_stack and openni_kinect. In the both the cases I got the same error. Please let me know if you have any leads.

### Thanks

No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected

Bus 002 Device 010: ID 05d5:6781 Super Gate Technology Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 038: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp.
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214520/kinect-for-windows(first-version)-with-ros/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2015-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that I had to do a bit of fiddling with some USB settings when I first set mine up. It was a while  ago so I don't remember everything, but I know that I have to run this command before I launch the freenect_stack:

> sudo bash -c 'echo -1 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend'

In addition to that, if you still see no devices connected, try unplugging the kinect from your laptop and plugging it back in and waiting about 5 seconds. Does the kinect for windows have a power adapter? If it does make sure that you have that plugged into the wall too or it won't work. The USB on your computer is not enough to power all the hardware in the kinect.

---

Originally posted by [troman](https://answers.ros.org/users/22738/troman/) with karma: 30 on 2015-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on 2015-07-27**:
Thanks! It worked!

**Comment by [troman](https://answers.ros.org/users/22738/troman/) on 2015-07-27**:
No problem, glad I could help!